# What do you call all military vehicles including airplane carrier?

Tags: word-request

What do you call all military vehicles including airplane carrier? I think vehicles also include aircraft carrier, but I am wondering if there's a word to replace "military vehicles", because it just sounds odds.

Answer (score 0):

"Military vehicles" doesn't sound strange to me, but it normally refers to land vehicles, in contrast to "military aircraft" or "military vessels" (boats, ships and submarines). Depending on the context, "military assets" might fit as a catch-all term, but that can also include troops, weapons and equipment, not just vehicles.

If you can explain the context in more detail, it may be possible to give a better answer.

Comment: There's also *materiel* which is a single word, but like "military assets" it includes general equipment and supplies as well as vehicles.